# Difference of pattern matching for "::(a,b)" and "List(a,b)"

Tags: list, scala, pattern-matching

To use `::` to pattern match a list:

```
val ::(a, tail) =  List(1,2,3)

// a: Int = 1
// tail: List[Int] = List(2, 3)
```

But with `List`:

```
val List(a, tail) = List(1,2,3)

// match error
```

I tried to figure out why the later one can't be matched, but without lucky.

I see in the `abstract class SeqFactory`, there is a `unapplySeq` method:

```
def unapplySeq[A](x: CC[A]): Some[CC[A]] = Some(x)
```

But when `x` is `List[Int]`, the return value is still `Some[List[Int]]`, I can't find where the magic is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is quite simple.

`List(1,2,3)` is a list containing 3 elements: `[1,2,3]`, similarly `List(head, tail)` is a list containing 2 elements: `[head, tail]`. It is **not** however a head and its tail.

```
scala> val hd :: tl = List(1,2,3) // val hd :: tl works the same as ::(hd, tl)
hd: Int = 1
tl: List[Int] = List(2,3)

scala> val List(a,b,c) = List(1,2,3)
a: Int = 1
b: Int = 2
c: Int = 3
```

So when you want to unapply a list using `List` you need to match the exact number of items in said list. Otherwise use the more historical `::` operator to get the head and the tail

Comment: @dhg you tell me this just as I closed the repl, oh gee thanks :P

Comment: Sorry, I still can't understand from your answer: why the `b` in `val List(a,b) = List(1,2,3)` can't match `List(2,3)`

Comment: `List(1,2,3)` means it's a list containing 3 elements, doesn't mean `case List(a,b) =>` can just match two single elements for `a` and `b`

Comment: @Freewind No. The pattern must have the same number of elements. If you want to match at least two, use `a :: b :: _` as pattern (or the more general `a +: b +: _` which works for all `Seq`s).

Comment: @Freewind because you can't map one list literal to another if they have a differing number of items. You have to remember that `List(1,2,3)` is Scala's list literal as well as its constructor (and de-constructor), what `List(1,2,3)` constructs is this: `1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil`, which is a structure completely different from `a :: b :: Nil` that `List(a,b)` would construct. So by writing `List(a,b)` you're telling the compiler: "I'm giving you a list of 2 items ending in Nil, here it comes", and then by giving it a 3-item list +Nil, the compiler gets pissed at you because you basically lied to it.

Comment: So when use pattern matching to match something returned from `def unapplySeq(...):Some[Seq[T]]`, that is actually very low level matching. And scala has rules: when you write `List(a,b)`, it just means you want to match a 2-elements list. When you write `List(a,b@_*)`, you want the `b` to match the tail